# Is a finitely additive measure with countably additive marginals countably additive?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be standard Borel spaces (for example, $\Bbb{R}$ with its Borel sigma-algebra).

Let $p$ be a probability measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $q$ be a probability measure on $(Y,\mathcal{B})$.

Let now $r$ be a finitely additive probability measure on $(X\times Y, \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B})$, such that for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$,
$r(A\times Y)=p(A)$ and $r(X\times B)=q(B)$.

Can we conclude that $r$ is countably additive? If not, are there conditions under which we can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $X = Y = [0, 1)$ with its usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. Consider the decreasing sequence $A_n$ of subsets of $X \times Y$ given by $A_n = \cup_{i = 1}^{2^n} [\frac{i - 1}{2^n}, \frac{i}{2^n}) \times [\frac{i - 1}{2^n}, \frac{i}{2^n})$. We see that $\lambda \times \lambda(A_n) = 2^{-n}$. Define $\mu_n$ on $X \times Y$ by $\mu_n = 2^n1_{A_n}(\lambda \times \lambda)$. We observe that both marginals of $\mu_n$ are $\lambda$. Now, let $\mathcal{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mu = \lim_{n \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \mu_n$. Then $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure with both of its marginals $\lambda$. However, $\mu$ is not countably additive. Indeed, if it were, then we would have $\mu(\cap_m A_m) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_m)$. Since $\lambda \times \lambda(A_m) = 2^{-m}$, we have $\lambda \times \lambda(\cap_m A_m) = 0$, so $\mu_n(\cap_m A_m) = 0$, whence $\mu(\cap_m A_m) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \mu_n(\cap_m A_m) = 0$. On the other hand, whenever $n \geq m$, we have $\mu_n(A_m) = 2^n(\lambda \times \lambda)(A_n \cap A_m) = 2^n(\lambda \times \lambda)(A_n) = 1$, so $\mu(A_m) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \mu_n(A_m) = 1$. But then $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_m) = 1 \neq 0 = \mu(\cap_m A_m)$, so $\mu$ is not countably additive.

Comment: There is a prop in Bourbaki Integration I ch.3 that the set of (complete, Radon) measures $\|\mu\| \le 1$ is vaguely (i.e. weakly) compact (follows from the fact that the space of continuous functions with compact support is barrelled), so each ultrafilter should have limit in this set. It looks like $\mu$ in your construction should be Radon complete measure. I think you may apply limit only to continuous functions in vague topology (not to characteristic functions of $A_m$ or $\cap A_m$ which are lower/upper semicontinuous). I may be missing something.

Comment: @dsh If you consider $\mu_n$ to be Radon measures on $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and take limits in the weak topology there, then the limit of the sequence is simply integration along the diagonal (properly normalized). It’s just a different limit here. If I’m not mistaken, integration w.r.t. $\mu$ should still be integration along the diagonal if the function you’re integrating is actually continuous. The same holds for characteristic functions of $A_m$. The difference is what they evaluate to on $\cap_m A_m$, which is the diagonal.

Comment: Because the characteristic function of the diagonal is not continuous, taking limits as Radon measures doesn’t directly tell you what the measure should evaluate to on the diagonal. It ends up being reconstructed through regularity conditions and $\sigma$-additivity. But taking limits as just finitely additive measures directly tells you $\mu$ should evaluate to zero on the diagonal, because that’s what all $\mu_n$ do.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, the limit is taken wrt different topology. Is the topology in $\mu = \lim_{n \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \mu_n$ convergence on Borel subsets?

Comment: @dsh Yes. I just meant $\mu(A) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \mu_n(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$.